# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc'

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to us 'pymc' to run my code however i have a problem with it
first , i use anaconda to manage my pycharm , my anaconda show i have successfully install 'pymc'

[image: my anaconda show i have successfully install 'pymc']

and then i try to import the module to my project so does my pycharm shows 'pymc' have successfully installed

[image: so does my pycharm shows 'pymc' have successfully installed]

[image: STILL ERROR]

Comment: PS.i have tried to remove it and install over and over . it just can't run on my pycharm

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiSyS.png)check pycharm have numpy module

watch this https://youtu.be/dxwB8KBLMcs and follow steps form 0.51

Comment: i can import numpy and use it

Comment: install numpy and check program

Comment: after i reinstall numpy i still can't import pymc
pycharm shows that i have installed pymc successfully however i can't import it to my program

Comment: Watch video ..link in above

Comment: It is maybe not a well-fromated answer here. Please edit it , especially the indentation and punctations

Answer (score 0):

You are running the wrong python interpreter in your command line. According to your PyCharm settings, **your packages are installed for "D:\Anaconda\python.exe"** and that is the python.exe that you should be calling. But according to your console output, executed interpreter is in another path.

In PyCharm, go to **"Run" > "Edit Configurations"** and make sure that the "Python interpreter" configuration there is also set to the one in "D:\Anaconda".

There also seems to be an issue that may be caused by PyCharm about the project settings. If the solution above does not work try the solution explained here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000164624-SOLVED-pycharm-seem-to-fail-to-add-to-PYTHONPATH